# Minify css and js with PHP compression script in Wordpress child-theme

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, compression, minify

I want to use next PHP script to serve combined, pre-gzipped and minified JS and CSS files. source code is available here: https://code.google.com/p/compress/

There is a WAMP localhost with wordpress installed.

And what I have done:

- added three files (jsmin.php, cssmin.php, compress.php) in child-theme's
  folder;
- added directory 'min' in child-theme folder;
- created file 'compress_timestamp.php'
- added code below into header.php (tried functions.php then tried first line
  of header.php)

  `require_once('compress_timestamp.php');         //load timestamp created by compress.php module sets field $compress_stamp=unix_timestamp

  if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'],'GZIP')!==false)

      $gz='gz';
  else
      $gz=null;
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="min/css_schedule_'.$compress_stamp.'.css'.$gz.'" />',PHP_EOL;
  //    the following scripts were combined into css_schedule
  //      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/menu.css" />',PHP_EOL;
  //      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/ThreeColumnFixed.css" />',PHP_EOL;
  //      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/sprite.css" />',PHP_EOL;
  //      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/iCal.css" />',PHP_EOL;`

- changed lines accordingly to child-theme and parent folders:

  ```
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />',PHP_EOL;
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../twentyfourteen/style.css"
  ```

What was missed and what is the right way to make it work?
 
And finally when all is done how to launch that script remotely on XAMP (VPS)?

Comment: Ok for now I did not succeed with that PHP compression method. Instead using Pagespped_mod for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good WordPress plugin, called [JCH Optimize](https://www.jch-optimize.net/), that minify css and javascript. Its very easy to install. It has both a free and paid version that comes with a ton more features that can be used to speed up your wordpress site. They also support Joomla.

The support for it is really good too.